# How to check a map of strings for a key and increment the key value by 1 every time a key exist in the map?

Tags: java, maps

I have a

```
Map<String,String> map = {
      BusDetails.BusDetail.DriverID=1,
   BusDetails.BusDetail.DriverSubID=2,
   BusDetails1.BusDetail.DriverID=1,
   BusDetails1.BusDetail.DriverSubID=2
    }
```

The datas are extracted automatically from an xml,
So if i want to add another
`BusDetails.BusDetail.DriverID`
key
I need to update the map with a key like this
BusDetails2.BusDetail.DriverID… etc.
is it possible?
So far i tried to extract the distinct keys from the map and i got the result as a list of String

[BusDetails,BusDetails1]

```
  private static void extractNodeDataToMap(Node node, 
  String parentNodeName, Map<String, String> outputMap) {
        int integer = 0;
        if (!(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE))
            return;
        if (!parentNodeName.equals(""))
            parentNodeName += ".";

        if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() > 1) {
            for (int ind = 0; ind < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); ind++) {
                extractNodeDataToMap(node.getChildNodes().item(ind), parentNodeName + node.getNodeName(), outputMap);
            }
        } else {
            String key = parentNodeName + node.getNodeName();
            List<String> list = outputMap.keySet().stream().map(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String ls : list)
                keyList.add(ls + parentNodeName.split("\\.", 2)[1] + node.getNodeName());


            if (outputMap.containsKey(key)) {
                for (String ls : list) {
                    String key1 = ls;
                    if (key1.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
                        Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
                        Matcher matcher = integerPattern.matcher(key1);
                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            integer = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());

                        }

                        System.out.println(integer + 1);
                        outputMap.put(key.replaceFirst("\\.", (integer + 1) + "."), node.getTextContent());

                    } else
                        outputMap.put(key.replaceFirst("\\.", "1."), node.getTextContent());
                }
            } else {
                outputMap.put(parentNodeName + node.getNodeName(), node.getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Sure, it is possible. Just extract the numbers from all keys and look for the highest. The new key would then have that number + 1. What did you try so far? Your other question already covered getting all the "BusDetailsX" strings, now just extract and parse the "X".

Comment: Are you sure a map is the right data structure for your use case? This looks like a job for a list.

Comment: yes, the requirement is a map of strings of Strings